# GLM R not all values or being returned

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

Hi I have a dataset where I have P number of predictors.  One of the predictors is "Color".  Color is always either "Green" or "Red". In the results of the glm call - which was btw - glm(target ~ color + age, data = d, family = binomial(logit)) - 
only "colorGreen" is there and it is not statistically significant.  Why does "colorRed" not have a row in the results?

Edit:  I am not looking for general logistic regression help.  This question is not a duplicate for another question that is a general question. This is a specific question.

Comment: If it did, you would have three rows, right?  Could you explain the meanings of those three parameters when there are only two categories?

Comment: I'm sorry what does "if it did" refer to?

Comment: The last line of your question: if "colorRed" had a row, you would have estimated three coefficients.  Could you say what they all mean?

Comment: I would have estimated that there would be two rows that pertain to color.  I would have estimated there would be a colorRed row and a colorGreen row.  There is only a colorGreen row.  I am wondering why colorRed is not in  results.

Comment: The answers to the duplicate explain that.

Comment: Can I just receive an answer in terms of my question?  I don't see the answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: This *exact* question has already been answered many times in many ways on this site.  The main problem is narrowing down the search, not finding answers.  You might try http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dummy+coding+regression+[R]+interpret .

Comment: So Red is baseline?